# When i compile a ASP .Net Application, i am getting the error, Internal Compiler Error (0xc0000005 at address 00DFFDDC): likely culprit is 'CODEGEN'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, visual-studio-2022

I am using legacy ASP .Net (framework 4.8) Website for the last 3 months. It was working fine in a AWS EC2 instance but when I tried the same in a new Windows 11 laptop. I am getting the Error: `Internal Compiler Error (0xc0000005 at address 00DFFDDC): likely culprit is 'CODEGEN'`.

The machine I am using is 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor. Also, the OS is windows 11 pro and the laptop is Dell latitude 3420.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, installing different versions of Visual studio but I am still getting the same error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptDZ9.png)

Comment: What exactly is the project type? ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?

Comment: ASP.NET Web site

Comment: it's a 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor. Also, the OS is windows 11 pro.

Comment: a web site, or a web site application? If a web site application, then clear out the bin folder, and try a re-build all (but do NOT do this if web site vs web site application). also, what frame work have you set this project to? (eg: 4.8). Try using any cpu if not. That compile error seems to suggest that its trying to use .net core - that don't make sense.